# Environment variables and commands lost after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, path, environment-variables

No sooner did I upgrade to windows 8.1 from windows 8, I found that I was unable to run commands from commandline like python, pip, cat,ls etc which are installed in the system when windows 8 existed. So how to restore those environmental variable settings back in windows 8.1?

**Update: Also not able to run commands after reinstalling the program e.g: "pip" was installed using windows binaries and yet the command line fails to recognize the pip command.**

Answer (score 0):

Add the directories in which these programs are installed separated by semicolons (`;`) to the PATH environment variable. You can modify it by going to Control Panel and searching for "environment variables" or "advanced system settings".

Comment: I know that, but that does not mean I can restore them all as I dont remember the programs installed and in which directory

Comment: If they are still installed then you can search for them.

Comment: This is not why I asked this question